# 403 with Apache and Symfony on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to run symfony on my apache installation (I'm using xampp for the whole package) and it keeps giving me a 403 error every time I try to access my website.

I've got vhosts set up with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servername.localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/me/web/server/web
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Alias /sf "/lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/web/sf"

    <Directory "/home/me/web/server/web">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/web/sf">
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

I've also added "127.0.0.1         servername.localhost" in my hosts file.

When I try to access "servername.localhost" it just gives me a 403 error. I've chmod'd 777 the symfony directory and my website directory in my home directory and used './symfony project:permissions' to let symfony check that permissions are set up correctly but still not result.

If I move my website directory into "/opt/lampp/htdocs" then it will serve it from there but still has problems access the symfony stuff such as the debug toolbar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify that NameVirtualHost has been set?

Comment: Yes, just above the information from the vhosts there, I have '
NameVirtualHost *:80'.

Comment: I have double checked the permissions of everything leading to my website's directory and some of them were not set to +x, so I've done that but am now presented with a blank page when I go to 'servername.localhost'. I have checked the access logs for the server and I am presented with '127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2010:11:01:33 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -'.

Comment: Try `servername.localhost/frontend_dev.php`.

Answer (score 0):

403 is usually *Directory Browsing Forbidden* (checking Apache's error log should confirm this).

Is there a default document (index.php) in your `/home/me/web/server/web` directory?

You've aliased Symfony into `/sf`, so you'd have to hit `http://servername.localhost/sf` to access it, not the top level `http://servername.localhost/`.

Comment: I have got an 'index.php' file in the '/home/me/web/server/web' folder; I also tried accessing 'servername.localhost/sf' but it gave me 404 error.

Comment: The alias is just to symfony's web folder, it just contains some images and css for the symfony branded error pages- nothing integral; it's usually removed from everything bar development environments.

Comment: Symfony has frontend web controllers, all urls should go through it (usually index.php) for dev there's also frontend_dev.php which provides more detailed errors.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony requires some rewrite rules, I don't see why the .htaccess wouldn't be present unless you've removed it- is mod_rewrite enabled?